# Overriding java interface in scala produces "method overrides nothing". Not using override produces "method already defined in scope"

Tags: java, spring, scala, swagger-codegen

I'm attempting to use a swagger-codegen generated interface in a scala project. Here's the code generated for my method:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "submitJob", notes = "Execute a job", response = GetJob.class, tags={ "jobs", })
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Get job info", response = GetJob.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/jobs/{requestId}",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    method = RequestMethod.PUT)
default ResponseEntity<GetJob> submitJob(@ApiParam(value = "",required=true) @PathVariable("requestId") UUID requestId,@ApiParam(value = "Job to be submitted" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody JobRequest body) {
    if(getObjectMapper().isPresent() && getAcceptHeader().isPresent()) {
        if (getAcceptHeader().get().contains("application/json")) {
            try {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(getObjectMapper().get().readValue("\"\"", GetJob.class), HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Couldn't serialize response for content type application/json", e);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default ApiApi interface so no example is generated");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

I'm attempting to override it with this:

```
  @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "submitJob", notes = "Execute a 
job", response = classOf[GetJob], tags = Array("jobs"))
  @ApiResponses(value = Array(new ApiResponse(code = 200, message = 
"Get job info", response = classOf[GetJob])))
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/api/v1/jobs/{requestId}"), produces = 
Array("application/json"), method = Array(RequestMethod.PUT)) 
  override def submitJob(@ApiParam(value = "", required = true) 
    @PathVariable("requestId") requestId: UUID, @ApiParam(value = "Job to 
    be submitted", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody body: JobRequest): 
    ResponseEntity[GetJob] = {
 // my method here
}
```

If I don't use override, I get a "method already defined in scope" error. If I DO use override, I get "method overrides nothing".

What gives?

Comment: You should provide more details. The following code compiles: https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/d05f258ebab3ff75dc938fe523c0cb22